# Could this be done with a simple equation to find the amount instead of looping?

Tags: python

I have created a fully working program that takes a number and subtracts 18% of that number from the number. It will then increase the number by 0.01 until the original number is reached.

My question is, could this be worked out with a simple algorithm/equation instead of creating a program to do it for me?

For example, If I wanted to reduce something by 1500 factoring in the 18%, I would have to actually reduce it by 1829, 1829 * 0.18 = 329, 1829 - 329 = 1500.

```
#Amount We need to reduce by
Red_Amt = 1500
Input_Amt = Red_Amt
#How much % of the reduction amount is added back on
Pool_Amt = (Red_Amt * 0.18)
#Actual amount we will be reducing by factoring in pool amount
Act_Amt = (Red_Amt - Pool_Amt)

print(Red_Amt)
print(Pool_Amt)
print(Act_Amt)

while Act_Amt < Input_Amt:
        Red_Amt = (Red_Amt + 0.01)
        Pool_Amt = (Red_Amt * 0.18)
        Act_Amt = (Red_Amt - Pool_Amt)

Red_Amt = round(Red_Amt)
Pool_Amt = round(Pool_Amt)
Act_Amt = round(Act_Amt)

print ("If you reduce by",Red_Amt)
print ("18% of your pool amount would be", Pool_Amt)
print ("And the actual reduction would be", Act_Amt)
```

Comment: I don't understand what your code is doing. Why are you adding `0.01` every step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use simple math, no code or equations needed:

```
1500 / (1 - 0.18) = 1829.27
```

---

When your program is run with the values `3200` and `0.45`:

```
Red_Amt = 3200  # value plugged
Input_Amt = Red_Amt
Pool_Amt = (Red_Amt * 0.45)  # value plugged
Act_Amt = (Red_Amt - Pool_Amt)

print(Red_Amt)
print(Pool_Amt)
print(Act_Amt)

while Act_Amt < Input_Amt:
        Red_Amt = (Red_Amt + 0.01)
        Pool_Amt = (Red_Amt * 0.45)  # value plugged
        Act_Amt = (Red_Amt - Pool_Amt)

Red_Amt = round(Red_Amt)
Pool_Amt = round(Pool_Amt)
Act_Amt = round(Act_Amt)

print ("If you reduce by",Red_Amt)
print ("18% of your pool amount would be", Pool_Amt)
print ("And the actual reduction would be", Act_Amt)
```

> It gives the output:
>
> ```
> 3200
> 1440.0
> 1760.0
> If you reduce by 5818
> 18% of your pool amount would be 2618
> And the actual reduction would be 3200
> ```

And the math agrees:

```
3200 / (1 - 0.45) = 5818.18
```

Comment: I think the increment by 0.01 part is missed.

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava I don't think that's actually useful in any way.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I feel a little silly I didn't notice it.